# need help to parse xml string

Tags: iphone

i need to parse this xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<imageset>
<category>
<image>SQUIRREL</image>
<image>FOX</image>  
<image>TIGER</image>    
<image>LION</image> 
</category>
</imageset>
```

i use this code to parse this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Config.xml"]]];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];
    NSLog(@"test.......... %@",test);
    }
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{            
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"image"]) {
        test = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        addelements = TRUE;
    }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{     
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"image"]) {
        addelements = FALSE;
    }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
        [test addObject:string];
}
```

But it adds only last object,displays like this in console.

```
test.......... (
    LION,
    "\n\n",
    "\n"
)
```

I need to add all image names in the xml file means {SQUIRREL,FOX,TIGER,LION}

how can i done,can any one please help me.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is this method:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{            
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"image"]) {
        test = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        addelements = TRUE;
    }
}
```

Every time an `image` tag starts, you overwrite the `test` variable with a new instance of NSMutableArray (leaking the previous object). You need to change it to something like this:

```
        if (!test) test = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

That is: only allocate a new array if there wasn't an old one already.

Comment: Thank u Dark Dust,I have a small doubt,there are the image names i need to add this image view what ever the extension it is, i mean i have images named SQUIRREL.jpg added in resources,how can i get it and display it in imageview

Comment: Add the ".jpg" extension via `-[NSString stringByAppendingString:]` and use that result as argument for `-[UIImage imageNamed:]`. Please read their respective class references for details.

Comment: is it possible to get by giving name i mean SQUIRREL,what ever the extension

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{ 
    [mutableString release];
    mutableString  = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];           
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"image"]) {
        if( !test  )  test = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 10];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{   
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"image"])  
        [test addObject: mutableString];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
       [mutableString appendString: string];
}
```

where test and mutableString are ivars declared in your view controller's header

Note: this is very simplified version.

Comment: if i use this last element is added 3 times

Comment: maybe, i haven't tested this. I've just shown a concept of using the parser.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Mahesh Babu yes you can also add the image  by giving the name only as for example......    

[UIImage imageNamed:@"SQUIRREL.jpg"];
```

Comment: @Mahesh babu this is possible you can do this way as well      ShadowImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"img"];

Comment: @Mahesh babu i tried this for you and it worked,what happened didn't get any reply or acceptance from your side...........Enjoy dude.....

Comment: No,it does n't display without extension

Comment: Sorry but worked for me.....I have images files but with extension PNG in bundle.....I just gave the file name without extension and it showed the image..Hard luck..Try with PNG images.....